# No disk space after installing Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, partitioning, system-installation, disk-management

I have just picked up a HP Proliant DL380 G5 Server, with 2 Dual Core Xeon Processors, 16Gb Ram and 4 x 146Gb SAS drives for £33 on ebay. Bargain. The idea was to get hands on with Ubuntu Server. I've started migrating home computers from Windows to Linux and want to move from Windows Home Server to Ubuntu Server.

Installation of US 14.04 seemed to go ok. However, i tried to install some additional packages and it is reported that there is insufficient disk space.

```
 matt@unicorn:/etc$ df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/unicorn--vg-root  2.6G  2.6G     0 100% /



matt@unicorn:/etc$ sudo parted -l swapon -s
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/unicorn--vg-root: 2823MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags 
1      0.00B  2823MB  2823MB  ext4


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/unicorn--vg-swap_1: 17.2GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop

Number  Start  End     Size    File system     Flags
1      0.00B  17.2GB  17.2GB  linux-swap(v1)


Model: Compaq Smart Array (cpqarray)
Disk /dev/cciss/c0d0: 440GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size   Type      File system  Flags
1      1049kB  256MB  255MB  primary   ext2         boot
2      257MB   440GB  440GB  extended
5      257MB   440GB  440GB  logical                lvm
```

Do I need to increase the size of /boot? Have I setup the installation incorrectly? Any help appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is your root ( `/` ) filesystem that is full because you only allocated 2.6 GB to it.  Since you set up lvm, and I'm assuming you used the recommended ext4 filesystem, you can do this fairly easily with:

```
sudo lvresize -L +10g unicorn-vg/root
sudo resize2fs /dev/unicorn-vg/root
```

Comment: during isntall I allcoated 20Gb, by the majority appears to have been given over to swap space. I guess that's where I messed up (somehow). I gave your suggestion, but a try. I got: 
    matt@unicorn:~$ sudo lvresize -L +10g unicorn-vg/root
    [sudo] password for matt:
    no talloc stackframe at ../source3/param/loadparm.c:4864,    leaking memory
      /etc/lvm/archive/.lvm_unicorn_2288_1013884933: write error     faile'd: No space left on device
      Volume group "unicorn-vg" metadata archive failed.

Any ideas?

Comment: @user3446764, it seems you have even exhausted the emergency reserve space.  You will need to find something you can delete to get back a bit of space.  You might clean out /var/cache/apt/archives, or remove some old logs from /var/log.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments from psusi's response, you could try using a tool such as [KillDisk](http://www.killdisk.com/downloadfree.htm) to wipe it, reformat it, and reinstall the os.